# Can we use API Calls in Selenium Pytest Framework?

Tags: python, api, selenium, post, pytest

I am trying to automate a test case wherein I first login to a website and then modify a drop down. I have automated the part until where I reach the correct page. The issue is, this drop down option is part of a table. The table has many similar elements. Also a few table tags are used as the first column is locked and others are horizontally scrollable. I am finding it very difficult to locate the correct drop down option to click.
When I check in the developer options, the drown modification is actually a POST request.
I know we can use API testing with pytest, but is it possible to integrate this within existing selenium framework?
Can I create a framework where in test_navigate will navigate me to the necessary page (pure selenium). Then test_modify_dropdown will use api call to send the POST request and modify the option. And then i can continue with further test_three?

All this in pytest by the way.

Comment: I think it will need to write code in JavaScript to call API, but later it would need to write another JavaScript code to replace elements in HTML - and this can be too complex. It would need to recreate all JavaScript code which page already uses when you simply click item.

Comment: Anything you can write in python can be run within pytest. So yes if you can get it running in selenium you can test it. It sounds like you’re just asking about how to do this in selenium in the first place though? In order to help, we’d need to see your code, ideally as a [mre]. As a warning though, generally selenium questions are tough to ask here because it’s just a matter of manually figuring out how to reference all the elements on a page, and that’s just work you need to do, not something we’re going to help with.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply be able to use the python `requests` module. A post request could look like this:

```
import requests

url = "url/for/your/api"

myobj = {'somekey': 'somevalue'} #json in request payload

x = requests.post(url, json = myobj)

print(x.text) #and/or get whatever data you want from the response.
```

Comment: This doesn’t always work for a stateful web app with a multi-stage drop down menu does it? This certainly works for well written sites but there are plenty of e.g. old government data browsers that are a total pain to scrape.